# @Query predicate, return navigation, not working

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I encounter a problem that I don't understand, I do a simple navigation on a view which browses a VideoGame Table with @Query from swift data, when I use it alone I obtain my list correctly and the navigation works correctly. however I want to use a #Predicate to filter only the games with the favorite property == true, it works correctly but in this version the back navigation no longer works. Any idea why? thanks in advance

Vue parente :

```
struct StoreGame: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink {
                FavoritListGameView()
            } label: {
                Text("Liste des favoris")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This version displays my favorites but the back navigation no longer works
Vue enfant :

```
struct FavoritListGameView: View {
        @Query(
            filter: #Predicate<VideoGame> {$0.favorite == true},
            sort: [SortDescriptor(\VideoGame.name,
            order: .forward)])
            var favorites: [VideoGame]
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section("Favories") {
                ForEach(favorites){ fav in
                    Text(fav.name)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

This version works correctly

```
struct FavoritListGameView: View {
    @Query private var myGames: [VideoGame]
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section("Favories") {
                
                ForEach(myGames){ game in
                    if game.favorite == true{
                        Text(game.name)
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "the back navigation no longer works" meaning what!?  The back button will disappear?  Or you cannot go back to StoreGame after clicking on the back?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the Back button stops working that is the actual problem but that you have an infinite loop where the @Query constantly keeps updating and makes the app unresponsive.

I am not sure what kind of UI you are trying to build here but you can not have a NavigationLink with a @Query/List/ForEach inside it. You should only have one "row" or single object view for each NavigationLink.

So one way forward is to move the NavigationLink inside the the loop like in the below example:

```
struct StoreGame: View {
    @Query(
        filter: #Predicate<VideoGame> { $0.favorite == true },
        sort: [SortDescriptor(\VideoGame.name,
                              order: .forward)]
    )
    var favorites: [VideoGame]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Section("Favories") {
                List {
                    ForEach(favorites) { fav in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text(fav.name)
                        } label: {
                            Text("Liste des favoris")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed after a few tests I had a bad logical approach to the @Query. Thank you for your valuable feedback

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand your query makes the view controls disappear.

Wouldn't a query like that work the way you want displaying only favourites while also being more readable

```swift
@Query(filter: #Predicate<VideoGame> {game in game.favorite == true}, sort: [SortDescriptor(\VideoGame.name, order: .forward)]) var favorites: [VideoGame]
```

Comment: This is just a different syntax, how can it change how the navigation works?